# File Search has encountered a problem in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I deleted some lib files from my existing project, and now everytime I want to do a file search, this error pops up at then end of the search :-

[image]
It's not really interfering with the search results I think, but it is kinda annoying since every search brings this error out. Any suggestions on how to stop this?

Comment: Did you delete keycloak-saml.xml?

Comment: Yes I did, but why would that cause a problem in the search?

Comment: Well, the error occurs, because the file doesn't exist, as the error message says. The file might be searched for, but throws an error, because of its non-existence.

Comment: Thing is I am not even searching for anything remotely related to that file, that file was not even relevant to my project before

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and probably duplicate, but I happen to encounter the same issue today, and found this solution:

On Package Explorer, select the your project then **press F5 (Refresh)**. Do this to all opened projects."**File search has encountered a problem**" error happens when your workspace is not sync with your file system (e.g. when you deleted a file that is currently opened in eclipse, etc.)